# My book uses Pythagorean theorem to solve for a constant in given equation. It doesn't seem legal.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[Equation I'm working with in my book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrBTp.gif)

$\left(5-\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}\right)\cos 3x - \frac32\sin 3x = (c\cdot\cos\phi)\cos 3x- (c\cdot\sin\phi)\sin 3x
$

[image: Solving for C]

The book factors c from the right side of the equation and sets c equal to the coefficients on the left side. Then uses Pythagorean's theorem to solve for c. I completely understand how the book did this process, I'm just trying to give a proof to myself that it works, and I can't find one. Thanks

Comment: What are $x$ and $\phi$?

Comment: A little more context would be helpful here.

Comment: Like the commenter above said, a little more context is needed. You provided us with an equation with **three** variables, $x,c,\phi$. Without telling us what $x$ and $\phi$ are, it's going to be tough answering the question.

Comment: They are not given. I am supposed to: Find real, positive constants c and φ for all real x. Sorry I should have given that in the beginning, however the book does not provide that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to show that there is $c$ such that $5 - \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}=c \cos \phi$ and $-\frac{3}{2}= c \sin \phi$. To this end we have to look for a number $c$ with

$c^2=(5 - \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2})^2+(-\frac{3}{2})^2$

Its your turn to compute $c$.

Comment: But how did you know that you could set c equal to the coefficients of the left side of the problem?

Comment: The equation $\left(5-\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}\right)\cos 3x - \frac32\sin 3x = (c\cdot\cos\phi)\cos 3x- (c\cdot\sin\phi)\sin 3x$ is valid for all $x \iff 5 - \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}=c \cos \phi$ and $-\frac{3}{2}= c \sin \phi$.